# Gridview dataBound add hyperlink to column data from code behind

Tags: c#, databound, rowdatabound, itemdatabound, databound-controls

Using grid view binding it from code behind:

I want to bind a particular column data into a hyper link so when it clicked it should do a download.

How to do that ?

Below is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= tbl.Columns.Count - 1; i++) 
{
    Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn boundfield = new Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn();

    if (tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString() == "Row") 
    {

        LinkButton lkbtn = new LinkButton();
        lkbtn.CommandName = i;
        lkbtn.CommandArgument = "dwnld";
        lkbtn.Font.Underline = true;
        lkbtn.Text = tbl.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString();

        boundfield.DataField = tbl.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString()
        boundfield.HeaderText = tbl.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString();

        GridView2.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundfield);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use grid template column with link button.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownload" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" runat="server">Download Something</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LinkButton lbBtn = sender as LinkButton;
  GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)(sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer;
  // Use item to get other details
...
...
}
```

Comment: because this grid is adding columns dynamically in this senario we cant use this